# Aggregate value of usrField SOLine not working

Tags: acumatica

I'm a bit lost here on what approach to take to get an aggregate value from my usr field on SOLineExt. My goal is a simple aggregation of the user field which is based on a this value from the SOLine:

`itemExt.UsrMinutes * (int)row.OrderQty;`

In the SOLineExt the value above is stored in UsrMultByQuant it gets the value fine but I can't seem to aggregate the the SOLineExt value to get the total of the UsrMultByQuant into my SOOrder field called UsrTotalWorkMinutes

```
     [PXDBInt]
     [PXUIField(DisplayName="TotalWorkMinutes")]
     [PXFormula(null, typeof(SumCalc<SOLineExt.usrMultByQuant>))]
     public virtual int? UsrTotalWorkMinutes{get;set;}
    public abstract class usrTotalWorkMinutes : IBqlField{}
```

I was referencing T200 Lesson 7, also I attempted to implement a fieldselecting (as instructed on Lesson 11.8 in t300) to try that approach for getting my total usr field value from the SOLineExt table with no success.

Any advice is appreciated, Thank you

Edit:
I removed the null from the PXformula and i am receiving this error now.
[image]
I also modified the dac slightly to have the PXParent attribute to select the current SOLine

```
[PXDBInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="TotalWorkMinutes")]
[PXFormula(typeof(SumCalc<SOLineExt.usrMultByQuant>))]
[PXParent(typeof(Select<SOLine,
                 Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>))]
public virtual int? UsrCuryWorkMinutes{get;set;}
    public abstract class usrCuryWorkMinutes : IBqlField{}
```

Still does not total my SOLineExt value and I am recieving the error above when null removed.

Comment: First parameter of PXFormula is the formula, you should remove the 'null'.

Comment: Just tried that with no success. I believe my PXParent most likely isn't correct?

Comment: Typically, you wouldn't put a PXParent in a DAC Extension.

Comment: Well... I was wrong. For Aggregate type, you indeed want to have 'null' as the first parameter.

Comment: HB do you happen to know if aggregates on DAC extensions is supported now? it's odd doesn't seem to be returning any values. Thanks

Comment: I don't know however I think the general statement that PXFormula does not support DAC extensions and custom fields is incorrect.

Comment: Hmm, the SumCalc is not functioning, would you happen to have any recommendations on what I should change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 extension classes from below should be enough to achieve the requested behavior (notice, fields UsrCuryWorkMinutes and UsrMultByQuant are of the decimal type):

[image]

```
public class SOOrderExt : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
{
    public abstract class usrCuryWorkMinutes : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBDecimal(2)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Work Minutes")]
    public virtual decimal? UsrCuryWorkMinutes { get; set; }
}

public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<SOLine>
{
    public abstract class usrMinutes : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Work Minutes")]
    public virtual int? UsrMinutes { get; set; }

    public abstract class usrMultByQuant : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBDecimal(2)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Work Minutes", Enabled = false)]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Mult<IsNull<SOLine.orderQty, decimal0>, SOLineExt.usrMinutes>),
        typeof(SumCalc<SOOrderExt.usrCuryWorkMinutes>))]
    public virtual decimal? UsrMultByQuant { get; set; }
}
```

There is no need for PXParentAttribute in SOLineExt because of the original SOLine.OrderNbr field already decorated with PXParentAttribute to aggregated other values from SOLine to SOOrder:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[PXCacheName(Messages.SOLine)]
public partial class SOLine : PX.Data.IBqlTable, ILSPrimary, IDiscountable, ISortOrder
{
    ...
    #region OrderNbr
    public abstract class orderNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected String _OrderNbr;
    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(SOOrder.orderNbr), DefaultForUpdate = false)]
    [PXParent(typeof(Select<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<SOLine.orderType>>, And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>>))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Nbr.", Visible = false, Enabled = false)]
    public virtual String OrderNbr
    {
        ...
    }
    #endregion
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ruslan, this is a much better approach. Thank you for taking the time to explain this it was very helpful and i'll be keeping this type of implementation in mind for the future. It worked flawlessly .